# Access Pandas Dataframe based on current (now) minute

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

I have a Dataframe with one row per minute. I need to access the row corresponding to the current minute

```
                          value
2022-01-12 11:27:24+01:00     a
2022-01-12 11:28:41+01:00     b
2022-01-12 11:29:36+01:00     c
2022-01-12 11:30:11+01:00     d
2022-01-12 11:31:03+01:00     e
2022-01-12 11:32:39+01:00     f
```

I have to match just the minute. I tried finding the current time both with `pandas` and `datetime` (code to reproduce it):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import datetime
start_idx=(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end_idx=(datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=+5)).strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

index_today = pd.date_range(start=start_idx, end=end_idx, freq='1T',tz='Europe/Rome')
# create random seconds
index_today=[i+ pd.DateOffset(seconds=np.random.randint(0,59)) for i in index_today]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_today, data=list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:len(index_today)]),columns=['value'])


now_pandas = pd.to_datetime("now").round(freq='min').tz_localize('utc').tz_convert('Europe/Rome')
now_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

out_pandas=df.loc[df.index.floor('Min')==now_pandas, :]
out_datetime=df.loc[now_datetime, :]

print('now pandas is ',now_pandas)
print('now datetime is ',now_datetime)
print('Current value found with Pandas:\n',out_pandas)
print('Current value found with datetime\n',out_datetime)
```

But sometimes they give different results:

```
now pandas is  2022-01-12 11:46:00+01:00
now datetime is  2022-01-12 11:45
Current value found with Pandas:
                           value
2022-01-12 11:46:08+01:00     b
Current value found with datetime
                           value
2022-01-12 11:45:35+01:00     a
```

What is the best and most robust way to do it?

Also, I noticed that if the dataframe is not tz-aware, then `pd.to_datetime("now")` gives the time in `utc` and I need to localize it, convert it and then turn it back to tz-naive. Any solution for that?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: putting a random in a "reproducible" example doesn't look like such a good idea.

Comment: so your question is why the results are different? - First, make sure you construct the date/time used for comparison equally; at the moment, `now_pandas` is *rounded* to the minute, while `now_datetime` gets clipped to the minute.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, MrFuppes what is the difference beween rounded and clipped to the minute?

Comment: Rounded means for example if the time is 12:30:31, you get 12:31. Clipped means 12:30:31 => 12:30, i.e. the seconds are just "cut off". A general suggestion: you shouldn't need Python datetime *at all* if working with time series data in pandas. pandas built-ins offer more options in many cases and work together well with other pandas functionality.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, now it's much clearer. so could you tell me what is the best way (using pandas then) to access a dataframe at the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to select row(s) based on the current minute? Make sure to set the condition correctly (as intended), e.g. by flooring the current time to the minute (clip to minute resolution). Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tz = 'Europe/Rome'
now = pd.Timestamp.now(tz)
print(now)
# 2022-01-12 12:11:38.796675+01:00

idx = pd.date_range(now.floor('d'), now.ceil('d'), freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=np.random.randint(0, 5, size=idx.size), columns=['value'])

out_pandas = df.loc[df.index.floor('min') == now.floor('min'), :]
print(out_pandas)
#                            value
# 2022-01-12 12:11:00+01:00      1
```

Comment: Thanks! What if df is not tz-aware?

Comment: @Gabriele then you can just omit setting the tz; e.g. `now = pd.Timestamp.now()` in the example.

Comment: Sure thanks, just noticed that pd.to_datetime("now") gives the time in UTC (different from my local time) while what you used e.g. now=pd.Timestamp.now() gives the right local time

Comment: @Gabriele might be related to pandas using UTC as default internally - if you can, work with the aware datetime (tz set) to avoid any ambiguities ;-)

Comment: OK, great to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the difference seems rather simple.

When using pandas you're rounding to the nearest minute, as it's a rounding it goes to the closest value (ie: next minute if it's after second 30).

When using datetime formatting you are merely dropping the seconds.

You can get the same behaviour by either using floor instead of round in pandas datetime of by rounding datetime.now() to the closest minute before formatting the result.

Or you may just don't care anymore of the difference now that you know where it's coming from and just stick with the pandas method (what I would do).

Note: another minor difference is that you are actually caling now() at two different times in your code once for pandas the other for datetime, hence there already exist a time difference between both. But it's not the main effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot minor issue but good to know!